# Simpe Java Time Parsing Issue

Tags: java, datetime, date, time

The following code will parse a String value of `2011-06-19T00:42:01` AND `2011-06-19T12:42:01` as `2011-06-19T00:42:01` which is incorrect. How can I fix this?

```
        //String t = "2011-06-19T00:42:01";
        String t = "2011-06-19T12:42:01";

        final String TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss";

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);
        java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(t);
        //parsedDate = Sun Jun 19 00:42:01 CDT 2011
```

Comment: Ah! Wow how'd I miss that.... `TIME_FORMAT` should be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `hh` for the hours which is the pattern for 12-hour format (with AM / PM). Use `HH` for 24-hour format and you should be fine.

The information was taken from the Java SE API documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

Comment: It's okay I'll give it to you. Thanks Nicolae for providing more info.